# Retrieve Clients from Projects User Belongs to

Tags: mysql

Users can have multiple projects and projects can have multiple clients.
How do I get all the unique clients from the projects a user belongs to?

Tables: 
- Users
- Projects
- Clients
- Project Clients

```
SELECT client_id, client_name FROM clients.. ? JOINS, USING.. ?.. what?
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if users can have multiple projects, you'll need a Project-Users table.

Given that, you can get what you want using either of these pieces of SQL:

```
select distinct c.id from
clients c
join projectclients pc on c.id=pc.clientid
join projects p on pc.projectid=p.id
join projectusers pu on p.id=pu.projectid
join users u on u.id=pu.userid
where u.id=3

select distinct c.id from
clients c join projectclients pc on c.id=pc.clientid
where pc.projectid in
(select projectid from
users u join projectusers pu on u.id=pu.userid
where u.id=3)
```